# Using two keyboards with Blender

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, navigation

I have two keyboards and would like to use keyboard #1 as usual and keyboard #2 mapped in another way. Is this possible? Currently the two keyboards are considered equal.

If this is not possible in Blender, is it possible to hack Windows so that e.g. Q on keyboard #1 emits a different character or modifier code than keyboard #2?

Possible use case: I have a separate numeric keyboard, and would like to use key 1,2,3 instead of MMB actions for pan, rotate, zoom, as the MMB button push or drag is really damaging my hand.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?